# PhoneGap, Onesignal push notification send to specific user in Cordova

Tags: php, cordova, onesignal

i have stored userId and push token in my database but not know how to send push notification to specific user from Onesignal Rest Api, i have tried my best but nothing solve my problem.

looking for your Suggestion and Response

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use OneSignal's [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) REST API call setting the `include_player_ids` field with the list of user's you want your notification to be sent to.